# Creating connection from ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, android-networking, android-testing

I have an Android application with very few permissions and explicitly no android.permission.INTERNET permission.

From an ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 I want to start a server that will receive test-commands to be execute against the application.

Using a ServerSocket will fail because Android will try to create the socket in the app's context and not in the instrumentation's.

Can this be done?

### Why do I want to do this?

By request, here is a bit of background.

I work on the test automation framework [Calabash-Android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/)

We run a server inside the instrumentation that receives commands and interact with the application. We would like to be able to test apps without asking the developer to set the internet permission.
This is the only part missing before we can test any app without modifications to the app.

A description of the architecture can be found here: http://blog.lesspainful.com/2012/03/07/Calabash-Android/

Comment: Tell us a little bit mor about your app, what does it actually do? why you need a remote server to test it?

Comment: I added the **Why do I want to do this** section with a bit of background.

Answer (score 0):

To use the instrumentation context instead of the app's context, pass:

getInstrumentation().getContext()

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make a ServerSocket using that context?